# not validate image pixel before upload image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to upload image normally using HTML and JS but I want to validate there pixel before uploading an image, if the image has proper in pixel then it should add on DOM otherwise not

This is my HTML code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Img Upload</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Hello</p>
            <input type='file' />
            <br>
            <img id="myImg" src="#" alt="Upload Image" height=200 width=200>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>


<!-- Js File -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Practice\imgUpload\script.js"></script>

</html>
```

here my JS code

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
     if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
          var img = document.querySelector('img');  // $('img')[0]
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to blob url

            img.onload = function() {
            // var width = img.naturalWidth,
            //     height = img.naturalHeight;

            // window.URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;
            if( width == 100 && height == 100 ) {
                imageIsLoaded;
            }
            else {
                alert ("add proper pixel image");
            }
         };           
      }
  });
});

function imageIsLoaded() { 
  alert(this.src);  // blob url
  // update width and height ...
}
```

after trying this above code it warns that your image is not in proper pixel but after the alert box close the image is uploaded. 
Simple: I want to add an image if the pixel is match otherwise it not add on DOM

Comment: Hello,
Just a Simple "I want to add image on dom if it is in proper pixel otherwise alert message will appear"

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You should be accessing `img.naturalWidth` and `img.naturalHeight` if you need access to the native pixel size of the image. `img.width` and `img.height` returns the size of the image as dictated by your markup: in this case, it's 200, which is incorrect.
2. When invoking the function `imageIsLoaded`, remember the parenthesis in the end, i.e. `imageIsLoaded()`
3. If you need access to the image element in the function, you need to pass it as an arugment, i.e. `imageIsLoaded(img)`. Then, in the function declaration, do `function imageIsLoaded(img)`, so within the function scope you have access to the uploaded image.

To control the showing/hiding of the image, you can simply set it to `display: none` by default, and the set it to `display: block` in the `imageIsLoaded()` function.

See example below:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var img = document.querySelector('img'); // $('img')[0]
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to blob url

      img.onload = function() {
        var width = img.naturalWidth;
        var height = img.naturalHeight;
        if (width == 100 && height == 100) {
          imageIsLoaded(img);
        } else {
          console.log("add proper pixel image");
          img.style.display = 'none';
        }
      };
    }
  });
});

function imageIsLoaded(img) {
  img.style.display = 'block';
  console.log(img.src);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <input type='file' />
  <br>
  <img id="myImg" src="" alt="Upload Image" height="200" width="200" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: I have a trying this way but the main point is that "If the Image is proper in Pixel then only it should be shown on DOM otherwise alert msg will appear" using your code it will be check but also if the image is not in proper pixel then also the image is added

Comment: @Akshayjadhav Not sure what you are testing, but I looked into this demo and image was not added if not in proper pixel. Maybe we are missing something.

Comment: @Akshayjadhav Updated the example to use `display` CSS property to toggle image showing.

Comment: @Terry Thank you so much for your help, yes, now It's running as I wanted it to

Comment: @Akshayjadhav Glad to be able to help :)